Multiple Testing p-value Adjustment and Preservation of Significant Differences
When adjusting for multiple hypothesis tests, a non-uniform distribution of p-values that has a promising-looking Q-Q plot ends up with all adjusted p-values far above 0.05. Are there other multiple testing adjustments which retain signficance for all points which diverge from the diagonal line? A minimal R-coded example is:
pValues <- seq(0.05, 1, length.out = 1000)
pValues <- c(0.00005 + c(0.001 * 2^(seq(0, 5, 0.5))), pValues)
> head(p.adjust(pValues, "BH"))
  0.69 0.69 0.69 0.73 0.82 0.96
> head(p.adjust(pValues, "holm"))
  1 1 1 1 1 1
> head(p.adjust(pValues, "fdr"))
  0.69 0.69 0.69 0.73 0.82 0.96

The corresponding Q-Q plot looks like:
library(qqplotr)
plotData <- data.frame(pValues)
ggplot(plotData, mapping = aes(sample = pValues)) + stat_qq_line(distribution = "unif") +
       stat_qq_band(distribution = "unif") + stat_qq_point(distribution = "unif")


